# how to create submenu of vertical menu in html

Tags: html, css

Please help me to create sub menu of the below design. sub menu should be align into just below the list.i my design menu and sub menu seems the same.

CSS:

```css
#vertmenu {
font-family:'Trebuchet MS';
font-size:14px;
width:250px;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
padding:0;
}

#vertmenu h1 {
display:block;
font-size:14px;
color:gray;
width:159px;
margin:0;
padding:3px 0 5px 3px;
}

#vertmenu ul {
list-style:none;
border:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#vertmenu ul li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#vertmenu ul li a {
font-size:14px;
display:block;
border-bottom:1px dashed #C39C4E;
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
width:160px;
padding:5px 0 2px 4px;
}

#vertmenu ul li a:hover,#vertmenu ul li a:focus {
color:#000;
background-color:#eee;
}

HTML Code:
```

```html
 <div id="vertmenu">
<h1>How to sell your images</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Home</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="2">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Computing</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="4">Web Sites</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="5">Games</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="6">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and sub menu visible by default not on the click of menu.

I have tried but it is not working .

help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please explain your question better so that we can point out the problem :)

Comment: its clear @Muhammad i want to create sub-menus of `<li>` and i have tried it on `sub munu1` and `sub menu 2` but its not working. it is visible like menu

Comment: See my answer I think you need that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#vertmenu {
font-family:'Trebuchet MS';
font-size:14px;
width:250px;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
padding:0;
}

#vertmenu h1 {
display:block;
font-size:14px;
color:gray;
width:159px;
margin:0;
padding:3px 0 5px 3px;
}

#vertmenu>ul {
list-style:none;
border:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#sub{
list-style: none;
}

#vertmenu ul li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#vertmenu ul li a {
font-size:14px;
display:block;
border-bottom:1px dashed #C39C4E;
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
width:160px;
padding:5px 0 2px 4px;
}

#vertmenu ul li a:hover,#vertmenu ul li a:focus {
color:#000;
background-color:#eee;
}

HTML Code:
```

```html
 <div id="vertmenu">
<h1>How to sell your images</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Home</a>
<ul id="sub">
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="2">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Computing</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="4">Web Sites</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="5">Games</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="6">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gitz you are welcome :)  and you can also up vote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Duncan_W/p52ndhxr/)

```
 <div id="vertmenu">
 <h1>How to sell your images</h1>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Home</a>
 <ul class="children">
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Computing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="4">Web Sites</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="5">Games</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" tabindex="6">Links</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>

#vertmenu {
 font-family:'Trebuchet MS';
 font-size:14px;
 width:250px;
 margin:0 0 0 20px;
 padding:0;
 }

 #vertmenu h1 {
 display:block;
 font-size:14px;
 color:gray;
 width:159px;
 margin:0;
 padding:3px 0 5px 3px;
 }

 #vertmenu ul {
 list-style:none;
 border:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

 #vertmenu ul li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

 #vertmenu ul li a {
 font-size:14px;
 display:block;
 border-bottom:1px dashed #C39C4E;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#666;
 width:160px;
 padding:5px 0 2px 4px;
 }

 #vertmenu ul li a:hover,#vertmenu ul li a:focus {
 color:#000;
 background-color:#eee;
 }
 li:hover > .children {
 display:block;
 }
 .children {
 display:none;   
 }
```

Notice the added children class on ul and the hover event.